# Firebase createUser method returning undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, firebase, angularfire

I've been pouring over Firebase's Docs trying to register a user. I'm using Angular 1.3 and Firebase 1.0.24.

I simply want to create a user.

Here are my Firebase rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
  }
}
```

My markup saves a user successfully to $scope.user ($scope.user.email and $scope.user.password).

In my controller, I have the following:

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('RegisterCtrl', ['$scope','$firebase', 'RegisterFactory', 
        function ($scope, $firebase, RegisterFactory) {

        $scope.submit = function() {

                RegisterFactory.Register($scope.user);

            }
        };
}]);
```

The controller sends the $scope.user info to the RegisterFactory, which is as follows:

```
angular.module('app')
    .factory('RegisterFactory', ['$firebase', function($firebase) {
        return {

            Register: function(user) {

                var ref = new Firebase('https://[redacted].firebaseio.com');

                ref.createUser({
                    email: user.email,
                        password: user.password
                }, function(error) {
                    if (error === null) {
                        console.log('User created!');
                        } else {
                        console.log('Error creating user', error);
                    }
                });
            }
        };          

}]);
```

When I enter info in the input fields and submit to register the user, I receive the following error:

`TypeError: undefined is not a function at Object.Register`and it points to the factory line 13:10 which is:
`ref.createUser({`

I know that Firebase Simple Login has been deprecated and that Firebase now carries Authorization functionality, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I'm following this portion of Firebase's Docs: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/password.html

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Firebase 1.0.24 you need to use the Firebase Simple Login library.

You can find the documentation on Github: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-simple-login/blob/master/docs/v1/api.md

The documentation you're referring is for the latest Firebase release.

Comment: This is exactly it. I forgot that installing AngularFire requested I use 1.0.24 as opposed to 2.0 and I downgraded. As a side note - is any version of AngularFire compatible with Firebase ~2.0? I like Firebase's built-in Authentication on 2.0...

Comment: I think 0.8.4 is compatible. No issues so far.